# jQuery Context Menu Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a custom right-click (context) menu for my website, but as the title says I'm failing completely. This is a JSFiddle example with all of the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rb49h/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Context Menu :P
    $context = $("#contextMenu");
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $context.fadeOut(300);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $context.css({top: e.pageY + "px", left: e.pageX + "px"});
            $context.fadeIn(300);
        }, 301);
    });
    $(document).bind("click", function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is("#contextMenu")) {
            $context.fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it kind of feels like there is some css missing there.I can see all the elements if I inspect it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bootstrap is setting your `.dropdown-menu` to `display:none` by default. If you override that, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fr4F9/

```
.dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

(As a side note, I don't care for the 300 ms delay. Makes it feel unresponsive and laggy).

Comment: The delay of the fadeOut effect is to make it look smooth and stuff... If I set 'transition:none;' on the '#contextMenu' object it works fine, no lag no nothing. Thanks anyway!